# How to combine Cross Join and String Agg in Bigquery

Tags: python, sql, database, google-bigquery

I am trying to go from the following table

```
| user_id | path                                                        | 
| 1       | Impression,Impression,Purchase, Impression, Email, Purchase |
```

to

```
| user_id | path                           | 
| 1       | Impression,Impression,Purchase |
| 1       | Impression, Email, Purchase    |
```

In essence I am trying to create a new row for each unique user in the table every time a 'Purchase' is encountered in a comma separated string.

From the little I have gathered I need to use a mixture of cross join and string agg but I tried using a case statement within string agg and was not able to get to the required result.

Is there a better way to do it in SQL (Bigquery).

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select 1 user_id, 'Impression,Impression,Purchase, Impression, Email, Purchase' path union all
  select 2, 'Impression,Purchase,Impression,Purchase, Impression, Email'  
)
select user_id, part
from `project.dataset.table`,
unnest(split(regexp_replace(path, r'Purchase,?\s*', r'Purchase|'), '|')) part
where trim(part) != ''
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Thank yo so much you have saved me hours of work. I had an additional question. Before getting to the step of combining the values as comma separated string I also have a date associated with each path value. That is impression and its corresponding date, email and its corresponding date.   My question is ----- Is it possible to take the date difference only where there is not Purchase in the path after what you have done above, can the two steps be combined? Let me know if you need additional information!

Comment: sure. post your question as a  new post with all relevant details and samples of input and expected output and ideally with what you tried - and we will answer/help you

Comment: consider voting up the answer if it was helpful :o)

Answer (score 0):

I think this query generates what you need. It uses [REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract_all) and [LTRIM](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#ltrim)

```
with data as (
select 1 as x, 'Impression, Impression, Purchase, Impression, Email, Purchase, Purchase, Something, Purchase' as y
UNION ALL
select 2 as x, 'Impression, Impression, Purchase, Impression, Email, Purchase, Purchase, Something, Purchase' as y
) 
select x, ltrim(q, ', ') from data, unnest(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(y, '.+?Purchase')) as q;
```